# run a shell command in the background and pipe stdout to a logfile with python

Tags: python, shell, subprocess, popen

I have a `.war` file I'd like to launch via python. I want it to run in the **background** so no log messages appear in my terminal. Also I would love to have the actual log output put into a logfile. This is the python code I use to solve this.

I had no luck yet. The process is **not** detached because I cannot run other shell commands after executing the script. The logfile is created but **no** log-output is appended there.

**EDIT**: To make things more clear. I want to enhance this script to run multiple java processes in the end. Therefore this python script should **spawn** those java processes and die in the end. How to achieve exactly that including the functionality of redirecting *stdout* to a file?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import subprocess
import re

platformDir = "./platform/"

fe = "frontend-webapp-0.5.0.war"
logfile = open("frontend-log", 'w')

process = subprocess.Popen(['java', '-jar', platformDir + fe], 
stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

for line in process.stdout:
        logFile.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually just simply had to give stdout the file handle like `stdout=logFile`. The solution with the for loop through the stdout would leave me in the python script process all the time

```
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

platformDir = "./platform/"

fe = "frontend-webapp-0.5.0.war"

logfile = open("frontend-log", 'ab')

p = Popen(['java', '-jar', platformDir + fe], stdout=logfile, stderr=STDOUT, bufsize=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can try it using Python 3:

```
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT

platformDir = "./platform/"

fe = "frontend-webapp-0.5.0.war"

logfile = open("frontend-log", 'ab')

p = Popen(['java', '-jar', platformDir + fe], stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT, bufsize=1)

for line in p.stdout: 
    sys.stdout.buffer.write(line) 
    logfile.write(line)
```

Comment: This almost worked. I removed `sys.stdout.buffer.write(line)` because I don't want any output being rendered somewhere else than the logfile. The logfile is being filled now. **But** the process is still not running in the background. I can't continue working in current shell after running the process. When I press `CTRL-C` I abort the application. *How to detach the processes?*

Comment: Could you try to add `p.wait()` to the end of the script and see if it works? Also you can use `screen` command in linux to detach.

Comment: No sadly did not work. Same procedure as above when I `CTRL-C` I abort the process.

Comment: `nohup python script_name.py &` this will detach your process.

Comment: I want to run my script as `./run-all.py`. It will then launch about 5 java processes which I all want to be detached/running in background. Your solution would work but it's not the way I want my script to work tbh. Thanks anyway!

Comment: isn't there a way to **spawn** subprocesses? So in the end the are decoupled from the python process? That's what I actually want. The script should only run and spawn processes and then die again.